# JAXP whether for XML parsing or XML binding?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jaxp, xml-binding

I know JAXP is for XML parsing but is it possible to achieve xml binding with the help of JAXP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For XML binding you could use JAXB, though.